# GRASS GIS v.out.ogr too many export too many feature shp

Tags: shapefile, grass-gis, export

I have a vector maps that contains 16 points (from v.information) I would like to export them in Shapefile format, but when I use v.out.ogr I got this message :

> Exporting 16 features... 28 features without attributes were written
> v.out.ogr terminé. 28 features (Point type) written to
> <Conlfuences_pts> (ESRI_Shapefile format).

So 28 points are exported.
(These points are from `v.to.point use= nodes` and then I used `v.clean` to suppress duplicate, but finally the duplicates are back when I try to export)
Do you know how to get rid of them and where the 28 points are coming from?

| Source date:     Wed Aug 30 15:42:52 2023                                  |
| Timestamp (first layer): none                                              |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Map format:      native                                                    |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|   Type of map: vecteur (level: 2)                                          |
|                                                                            |
|   Number of points:       28              Number of centroids:  0          |
|   Number of lines:        0               Number of boundaries: 0          |
|   Number of areas:        0               Number of islands:    0          |
|                                                                            |
|   Map is 3D:              Non                                              |
|   Number of dblinks:      0                                                |
|                                                                            |
|   Projection: UTM (zone 40S)                                               |
|                                                                            |
|               N:      7671915.0001    S:      7659685.0001                 |
|               E:       371965.0001    W:       352930.0001                 |
|                                                                            |
|   Digitization threshold: 0                                                |
|   Commentaire:                                                             |
|                                                                            |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

| Source date:     Wed Aug 30 15:42:52 2023                                  |
| Timestamp (first layer): none                                              |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Map format:      native                                                    |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|   Type of map: vecteur (level: 2)                                          |
|                                                                            |
|   Number of points:       16              Number of centroids:  0          |
|   Number of lines:        0               Number of boundaries: 0          |
|   Number of areas:        0               Number of islands:    0          |
|                                                                            |
|   Map is 3D:              Non                                              |
|   Number of dblinks:      0                                                |
|                                                                            |
|   Projection: UTM (zone 40S)                                               |
|                                                                            |
|               N:      7671915.0001    S:      7659685.0001                 |
|               E:       371965.0001    W:       352930.0001                 |
|                                                                            |
|   Digitization threshold: 0                                                |
|   Commentaire:                                                             |
|                                                                            |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

```
run_command("v.to.points",
            overwrite = True,
            flags="t",
            input="Strahler_dissolve",
            layer="1",
            type="line",
            output="Confluence_d",
            use="node",
            dmax=100) 

run_command("v.clean",
            overwrite = True,
            input="Confluence_d",
            output="Confluences",
            type="point",
            tool="rmdupl",
            thres=0.00)

run_command("v.out.ogr",
            overwrite = True,
            input="Confluences",
            layer="1",
            type="point",
            output=options["voutogr3_output"]+"\Pts_Confluences",
            format="ESRI_Shapefile")
```

Comment: Can we see the outputs from: `v.info` for both the original line map, and the resulting points map. And also the full `v.to.points` command the the `v.out.ogr` command that you ran?

Comment: Hi @Micha, I add the requested informations

Comment: It seems to me that the vector line map "Strahler_dissolve" has 16 line features, and this results in 28 nodes - some are confluence points and some are the start of the streams. Do you have a stream network with 16 stream reaches? and 12 upstream start points? Maybe a map image would help.

Comment: @Micha, I m fine with having 28 pts from v.to.points, but my question is why when it export the vector maps with 16 pts result of v.clean it export the 28 pts (from the vector maps before the cleaning) although v.infos indicates 16 pts

Comment: Can you show why you think there should be only 16 points? Where are the duplicates that you expect to be cleaned?

Comment: Because from v.info "Number of points: 16" after the cleaning